# 301 redirect a Trailing Slash in .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a wordpress site.

This code redirecting www.site.com/category/ to www.site.com/category for duplicate content.

but www.site.com/wp-admin/ doesn't work. How do I fix it?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301]
```

I solved the problem.

is this code safe?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `www.site.com/wp-admin/ doesn't work`?

Comment: I can't login to /wp-admin/

Answer (score -1):

In this case you must have to access via FTP client like FileZilla or login to your hosting cPanel.

You can try the following code :

**

### ROptions +FollowSymLinks RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

**

Reference: http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/85/Using+.htaccess+rewrite+rules#gs